# How to make a tree plot in caret package?

Tags: r, plot, rpart, r-caret

I'm using caret package to model the data using rpart package.

```
library('caret')
data(iris)
formula <- as.formula(Species ~.)
t <- train(formula,iris,method = "rpart",cp=0.002,maxdepth=8)
plot(t)
```

As a result I get object 't' and I'm trying to plot this object to get tree plot. But the result look like that:
[image]

Are there any way to make a tree plot from caret train object?

Comment: If your tree plot is simple another option could be using "tree map" visualizations. Not the same as a treeplot, but may be another interesting way to visualize the model. See [treemapify](http://mlbernauer.github.io/R/20150309_treemaps_with_ggplot2.html) in ggplot

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The object returned from `caret::train()` is a list.  The element `finalModel` contains your model.

Try this:

```
plot(t$finalModel)
text(t$finalModel)
```

[image]

Answer (score 51):

nicer looking treeplot:

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(t$finalModel)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you control for how many depths you want to draw?

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem, but the answers given here wouldn't solve it, since I used a random forest instead of a tree, the following is for all coming here having the same issue:

In short: A tree can only be displayed when the method is something like:

```
method = "rpart"
```

Using a random forest

```
method = "rf"
```

will result in the following plot:
[image]

Extended answer already here:
[Plot decision tree in R (Caret)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636186/plot-decision-tree-in-r-caret)