# Plot decision tree in R (Caret)

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, decision-tree, r-caret

I have trained a dataset with `rf` method. For example:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(
                     method = "LGOCV", 
                     repeats = 3, 
                     savePred=TRUE,
                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                     preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.95)
                    )

preProcessInTrain<-c("center", "scale")
metric_used<-"Accuracy"
model <- train(
               Output ~ ., data = training,
               method = "rf",
               trControl = ctrl,
               metric=metric_used,
               tuneLength = 10,
               preProc = preProcessInTrain
              )
```

After thath, I want to plot the decission tree, but when I wirte `plot(model)`, I get this: [`plot(model)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnEh.png).

If I write `plot(model$finalModel)`, I get this : [`plot(model$finalModel)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVTYv.png)

I would like to plot the decission tree...

How can I do that? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model you are using is random forest, which is not a single decision tree, but an ensemble of a large number of trees. Plotting the final model will plot the error rates on the training and test datasets as # of trees are increased, something like the following.

[image]

If you want a single decision tree instead, you may like to train a CART model like the following:

```
model <- train(
  Species ~ ., data = training,
  method = "rpart",
  trControl = ctrl,
  metric=metric_used,
  tuneLength = 10,
  preProc = preProcessInTrain
)
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(model$finalModel)
```

Now plotting the final model as above will plot the decision tree for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have one question. What means de blue, green, black and red lines? I mean, what are the differences between them?

Comment: Thanks for the question. The black line represents the overall OOB error, whereas the other three colored lines represent the OOB error accross each of the 3 classes in the training data (I used training data with 3 different class labels).